# Passing part of a structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, char, structure

I have a structure declared like so:

```
typedef struct {
    char InstrumentDB[128];
    char GeneralSettingsDB[128];
    char LiveDB[128];
    char SystemsDB[128];
} Address;
```

However when I try to call the function `OpenDatabase(char* filepath, ...)` I get an error. I call it like this:

```
OpenDatabase(Filepath.InstrumentDB, db);
```

However when I create a new char array of the same size but in a separate variable not attributed to the structure it works? Why is this? Surely they are of the same type?

EDIT: Filepath.InstrumentDB is declared like this :

```
Address Filepath;
Filepath.InstrumentDB = "/root/BBBTest/Instruments.db";
```

And this is the error i get: `error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[128]’ from type ‘char *’`

Comment: "I get an error" - What error?

Comment: And how is `Filepath` defined and initialized?

Comment: Please add a minimal example that shows the error (and include the error in your question).

Comment: Compiles fine for a super minimal exampel: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f463003547050e14aef069974e57ad95 . What's your issue.

Comment: To copy a string, you cannot just assign it but have to use strcpy(Filepath.InstrumentDB, "...")

Comment: @AxelKemper thanks, thats fixed it. The fact it worked when using char address[128]="..."; is confusing though if thats the case. However I should have realised as I have had this same error before!

Comment: @Mst137: this scenario works because it's initialization during allocation. It's a totally different case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Invalid Initialization

Your code is invalid:

```
Address Filepath;
Filepath.InstrumentDB = "/root/BBBTest/Instruments.db";
```

If I try this with a minimal example, I get this error with LLVM 7.3:

```
~/tmp> gcc -Wall -pedantic -ansi test.c
test.c:19:24: error: array type 'char [128]' is not assignable
  address.InstrumentDB = "/root/BBBTest/Instruments.db";
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

You are attempting to override a static initializer. The memory for your InstrumentDB field is already allocated at when you create your structure. Instead, simply reuse it by copying the data you need.

### Working Minimal Examples

#### With a Dynamic Copy

This works as intended:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct {
  char InstrumentDB[128];
} Address;

void OpenDatabase(char* filepath) {
  /* do stuff */
  printf("%s\n", filepath);
}


int main(int ac, char **av) {
  Address address;
  strcpy(address.InstrumentDB, "test");
  OpenDatabase(address.InstrumentDB);
}
```

*A Quick Note on String Copy Actions:*

C-strings are null-terminated by convention. Note that in the above example I used the `strcpy()` function for the sake of simplicity. However, should your input string come from a non-static source (ie I/O of any kind like user-input, file input, ...), not be null-termined, or your software be constructed in a way that may allow to modify the intended purpose, you'd want to guard against [buffer overflow/overrun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) errors by using explicit copy actions (for instance `strncpy`, or `strlcpy`/`lstrcpy`, depending on target environments).

Thanks to users StoryTeller and iwin for pointing this out.

#### With a Static Initialization

Replacing the initialization line in the sample above with this would also work:

```
int main(int ac, char **av) {
  Address address = {
    "test2"
  };
  OpenDatabase(address.InstrumentDB);
}
```

Comment: Should perhaps use `strncpy` rather than `strcpy`.

Comment: @iwin: haven't coded in C in a few years. Why would this be an issue in this simple case, where the string is a static string not coming from an input? If this was user-input or a passed variable, I'd agree with you.

Comment: @haylem, because the struct definition may be tucked away in some header, while someone innocently changes the static initializer and forgets to count the characters.

Comment: @StoryTeller: right. So that's what I'm saying: it's not an issue for this example.

Comment: @StoryTeller: and in this case, dealing with strings, then `strlcpy` would be the more correct approach anyways.

Comment: It is for the OP where the path is quite long. IMO answers should strive to answer the question in the best and safest way. Not just be internally correct. You got *my* vote, but I still find this a weak point in your answer.

Comment: Not if you are bound to using only the standard library. But we digress.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Hmm, I'd generally agree, but I also sometimes find that packing too much in answer is not the right way, as it can bring deluge of - valid but overwhelming - questions for the OP. If Use strncpy, then he'll have to understand sizeof() as well, for instance. And null-terminated strings, which he may not understand yet. As the OP seemed somewhat new, I didn't want to pile too much on. Whereas if it was a question security.stackexchange.com or cryptography.stackexchange.com, I'd definitely lean your way.

Comment: @StoryTeller: true about the standard library, my bad, it's not part of POSIX either. Sorry. Like i said, haven't coded C in years, so I only fired up an emacs and compiler for a quick whirl. I was more afraid that iwin was pointing out a gap in my knowledge or that my understanding got obsolete. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @StoryTeller: amended the answer to cover that, though by leaving the code sample in its simple form.

Comment: @iwin: amended. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An array cannot be assigned to.  You'll get the same type of error if you do

```
int main()
{
     char buf[10];
     buf = "Hello";
}
```

Instead, you need to use string functions

```
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
     char buf[10];
     strcpy(buf, "Hello");
}
```

More generally, you need to read up on strings in C.    The reason `<string.h>` exists is because numerous operations involving strings (which are represented as an array of `char`) do not work in the way you are expecting.